# Why uploaded image is not saved in specific folder in spring?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to upload an image in specific folder. After clicking button, ajax return the success alert, but file is not saved in the folder.

Here is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/echofile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> echoFile(HttpServletRequest  request,
            HttpServletResponse response ,  @ModelAttribute("uploadedFile") UploadedFile upldfile) throws Exception {
     HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

     if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){

         InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
          // MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("file");

            MultipartFile file = upldfile.getFile();
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println("vcvvvvvvvv"+fileName);
            upldfile.setFile(file);

            Long size = file.getSize();
            String contentType = file.getContentType();

            InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);


            map.put("fileoriginalsize", size);
            map.put("contenttype", contentType);
            map.put("base64", new String(Base64Utils.encode(bytes)));

            try {


                inputStream = file.getInputStream();

                   File newFile = new File("E:/Java_Project/EmployeeRegistrationForm/src/main/webapp/resources/image/"+ fileName);
                   if (!newFile.exists()) {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                   }
                   outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                   int read = 0;
                  byte[] byt = new byte[1024];

                   while ((read = inputStream.read(byt)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(byt, 0, read);
                   }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }


     }
     return map; 


     }
```

and Here is my ajax call:

```
  function uploadImage() {

            var file = $('[name="file"]');
            //var imgContainer = $('#imgContainer');

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            var filename = $.trim(file.val());

            if (!(isJpg(filename) || isPng(filename))) {
                alert('Please browse a JPG/PNG file to upload ...');
                return;
            }

             $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/EmployeeRegistrationForm/echofile",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(document.getElementById("fileForm")), 
                //data: formData,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                aync: false,
                modelAttribute:'uploadedFile',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                contentType: false,
             /*  }).done(function(data) {

                 var img = '<img src="data:' + data.contenttype + ';base64,'
                      + data.base64 + '"/>';
                  alert("success");

             }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

                  alert('File upload failed ...');
              });  */

            success: function(response){

                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(response);

            },

            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });   
        }
```

when I have clicked upload button,alert works of success part. Console of both eclipse and browser do not show any error. But file is not save in resources/image folder. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a form that submits multipart form data to a url. And you have a controller for that.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createProject(@ModelAttribute Product product, BindingResult bindingResult,
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile, Model model) throws IOException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("BINDING ERROR: " + bindingResult.toString());
    }
    if (productService.isImageValid(multipartFile)) {
        product.setImage(multipartFile.getBytes());
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid Image!");
    }

    productService.saveAndFlush(portfolio);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully saved project!");

    return "redirect:/products";
}
```

Check if image is valid:

```
public boolean isImageValid(MultipartFile multipartFile){
    try {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(this.convertToFile(multipartFile));
        if (image!=null) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: "+e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return false;
}


private File convertToFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();
    return file;
}
```

Your form might look like that:

```
<form th:action="@{/products/create}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    Product Id: <input type="number" name="id"></input>
    Choose an image: <input type="file" name="image"></input>

    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```